# How to make dynamic content positioning?

Tags: html, css

You see tons of sites with their content very nicely centered, like dribbble.com for example. Even when the window is resized, the content stays centered and when it hits against the side of the page, stops.

I would really like to get this behavior on my website but I'm not really sure how to go about the CSS to make this happen... I'm aware of the `position` property and using percentages for the left/right positioning but it doesn't seem to be quite that simple.

Can someone help me figure out how to do something like this?

Comment: what is your site? dribble.com uses the well known `margin:0 auto` for its `#content` `div` (`width` is required)

Comment: @Sotiris it's a private site for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard practice is to have a div that wraps your centered content, such as...

```
<div id="container">
   ...everything you want to center
</div>
```

And the in your CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 970px;
  margin: 0 auto; /*first value the margin for top and bottom, auto puts automatic margins in the left and right to center the content*/
}
```

Comment: Obviously, you will need to specify a width for the container in order for this to be effective.

Comment: @Pete, woops! Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @Duopixel If there is stuff with absolute positioning inside my container will this still work?

Comment: You can also add `max-width` to prevent horizontal scroll-bars.
`width: 970px; max-width: 90%;`

Comment: @Tory Waterman if the element in which use this method has `position:relative` or `position:static` (the default) will work independently the position of its children

Comment: @Tory Waterman Yes! But you need to give the container a `position: relative;` without specifying `top`, `left`, …

Answer (score 3):

> I'm aware of the position property and using percentages for the left/right positioning but it doesn't seem to be quite that simple.

It's simpler.

```
selector-that-matches-a-container {
    width: <some length>
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: If a lot of my material has `absolute` positioning, this won't work, right?

Comment: No. Absolute positioning is in respect to the containing block. If your containing block is currently the window, then you just need to establish one in the DOM — by setting `position: relative` on the container.

Comment: I realize this might be a bit of a vague question without you seeing my code, but the left end of my page will not scale down, it seems there is always a pretty wide margin between the left end of the page and my content... I can't seem to find any kind of positioning or margin property that might be causing this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with this CSS:

```
.content {
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  right:100px;
}
```

Comment: @Tory Waterman The difference between my answer and the `margin:0 auto` is that my answer will keep a constant margin (100px) on each side. The other answer will adapt the `div` to the content. Now you choose the one you prefer `;o)`

Comment: The question asks about a fixed width design, which is centered until the window is too narrow and then is left aligned — so no. And since that doesn't work in older versions of IE — doubly no.